# How can I serve only statics files on Google App Engine?

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I wrote a game with HTML5. Locally, it only works if I run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

And then I open `localhost:8000`. So, just a bunch of .html and .js files won't work. I want to put my game online and because of this Github (Pages) is out of question, because it won't work.

This is the part of the code I need a server for (I do realize that `localhost:8000/res/` won't work on App Engine, I'll need to change the address):

```
var mapFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
var self = this;
mapFile.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/res/map" + mapNumber.toString() + ".txt", true);

mapFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (mapFile.readyState === 4) {
    if (mapFile.status === 200) {
      self.lines = mapFile.responseText.split("\n");
      self.loadTilesFromLines();
    }
  }
};

mapFile.send(null);
```

So, I heard that Google App Engine would work, it supports Python and is very popular. Now, I don't need anything like what they have in their documentation (which is pretty well-written):

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

All I need is a SimpleHTTPServer that allows me to open my `index.html` on `my-app.appspot.com`.

I did try the example and got it up and running, but I can't force my browser to open `index.html` or `src/` or even `res/`.

So, I am not even sure if Google App Engine supports what I'm trying to achieve here. The documentation just focus on building applications that use Python and all I needed with Python was a SimpleHTTPServer, which I don't think I need with App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is very doable on what you're trying to achieve here. Since you just want to serve static files it is very simple and you don't need to include any Python code.

Let's assume that you have this following structure:

```sh
└── my-game
    ├── app.yaml
    └── static
        ├── index.html
        ├── js
        │   └── script.js
        └── res
            └── map.txt
```

This `app.yaml` should look like this:

```sh
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static/
```

After you're going to install the [Google App Engine SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) (if you didn't do that already), you will be able to run the `dev_appserver.py` command from your terminal. If you have the above structure try to run it using the following:

```
$ dev_appserver.py /path/to/my-game
```

If everything went smoothly you'll be able to see your `index.html` on `http://localhost:8080`, the `map.txt` on `http://localhost:8080/res/map.txt` and you should be able to figure out the rest.

Note that you could still run your application using the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from within the `static` directory and test it on `localhost:8000`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer (well-written and very clear), it worked perfectly on localhost. I'll just have to test it with my-app.appspot.com address now.

Comment: @user996056 that was the fastest accepted answer ever :) It should work fine when deployed.. but if you have any issues just ping here.

Comment: `2013-02-04 13:51:37,608 ERROR appcfg.py:2203 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. Aborting. 
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Bad Owner List (400)
The owner list is invalid.`

@Lipis, this only started happening after I changed my app.yaml to yours. That's the error I get when updating. It used to work just fine.

Comment: @user996056 check the application name and make sure that you have that correct.

Comment: Facepalm, that was it. The problem now is that it's not deploying/uploading src/ and style.css and whatnot, it's only uploading index.html.

Comment: @user996056 I updated my answer.. yes for some reason when it's in the root it's not uploading these files... put all your static files in the static folder and update the app.yaml accordingly.